# Why Angular 14 async http client call doesn't await to get response?

Tags: angular, async-await, promise, observable

I have a problem with angular 14 async / await that is not working correctly
here is my service that calls a "HttpClient" get request that should be async:

```
export class ShopService {
  DYNAMIC_PROPERTY_GETALL_SELECT_ITEM_URL = environment.BASE_URL + 'DynamicProperty/GetAllSelecItem';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }

  async getAllDynamicProperties(): Promise<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>> {
    var result: ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO> = ApiResultModelDTO.GetNullModel<SelectItemDTO>();
    this.httpClient.get<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>>(this.DYNAMIC_PROPERTY_GETALL_SELECT_ITEM_URL)
      .subscribe({
        next: async (response: ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>) => {
          result = response;
        },
        error: async () => {
          result = ApiResultModelDTO.GetNullModel<SelectItemDTO>();
        }
      });
    return result;
  }
 }
```

and I want to use await in my component when I call this method to return my response
here is my component call method :

```
  async loadDynamicProperties() {
    var result = await this.shopService.getAllDynamicProperties();
  }
```

but this await in "loadDynamicProperties" not working and my result is not the response I get in actual http call.

Why is not working?!
What I'm missing?

Comment: You return the result outside of the subscription.

Comment: @derstauner I can't return response in next or error, because method has a return type, and it won't recognize the return in next and error section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to convert your observable to a promise you can leverage the `firstValueFrom` or `lastValueFrom` operators.

See guide: https://obaranovskyi.medium.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-observables-and-vs-promises-rxjs7-296877376668

```
async getAllDynamicProperties(): Promise<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>> {
  const getItems$: Observable<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>> =
    this.httpClient.get<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>>(this.DYNAMIC_PROPERTY_GETALL_SELECT_ITEM_URL)
      .pipe(
        catchError(
          () => ApiResultModelDTO.GetNullModel<SelectItemDTO>()
        )
      )

  return firstValueFrom(getItems$);
}
```

```
async loadDynamicProperties() {
  const result = await this.shopService.getAllDynamicProperties();
}
```

Note: This is not a recommended pattern for handling asynchronous code in Angular due to the ubiquity of RxJS and its power compared to promises (even for single value observables like HTTP requests). If your use case supports it, I would recommend working with RxJS not against it

---

An example of how to achieve this using RxJS:

"normal" usage, i.e. processing in subscribe code, leading to duplicate subscribe blocks

```
getAllDynamicProperties$(): Observable<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>> {
  const getItems$: Observable<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>> =
    this.httpClient.get<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>>(this.DYNAMIC_PROPERTY_GETALL_SELECT_ITEM_URL)
      .pipe(
        catchError(
          () => ApiResultModelDTO.GetNullModel<SelectItemDTO>()
        )
      )

  return getItems$;
}

loadDynamicProperties1(): void {
  this.shopService
    .getAllDynamicProperties()
    .subscribe({
      next: (dynamicProperties: ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>) => {
        console.log(dynamicProperties) // Duplicated
      }
    });
}

loadDynamicProperties2(): void {
  this.shopService
    .getAllDynamicProperties()
    .subscribe({
      next: (dynamicProperties: ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>) => {
        console.log(dynamicProperties) // Duplicated
      }
    });
}
```

Avoiding multiple duplicated `subscribe` blocks by leveraging the `tap` operator, e.g.

```
getAllDynamicProperties$(): Observable<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>> {
  const getItems$: Observable<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>> =
    this.httpClient.get<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>>(this.DYNAMIC_PROPERTY_GETALL_SELECT_ITEM_URL)
      .pipe(
        tap(
          (dynamicProperties: ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>) => {
            console.log(dynamicProperties) // Not duplicated
          } 
        ),
        catchError(
          () => ApiResultModelDTO.GetNullModel<SelectItemDTO>()
        )
      )

  return getItems$;
}

loadDynamicProperties1(): void {
  this.shopService.getAllDynamicProperties().subscribe(); // Subscribe now only needed to trigger the HTTP request
}

loadDynamicProperties2(): void {
  this.shopService.getAllDynamicProperties().subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It works the way I exactly want, but if this is not a recommended pattern, how can I handle these types of requests with RxJS ???

Comment: Typically instead of returning a Promise here, you would return the observable itself (basically return `getItems$` instead of `firstValueFrom`) and then you would call `this.shopService.getAllDynamicProperties().subscribe( // .. code goes here )`. No need for async/await. It is worth reading about the topic, there should be lots of information online :)

Comment: yeah, I know that but what if I want to return the result of subscribe of my service calls ? instead of calling subscribe() for every call in where I use that method, I want to just return the value and result in one place, is there any recommended pattern for this use case ?

Comment: I have added an additional RxJS implementation below my original answer. tl;dr is you can do any processing you need inside the observable stream using various operators, which means you then only need to call `.subscribe()` in every component in which you want to trigger that functionality. Avoids duplicate code. Naturally if you have different processing that you want to do in different components, you always have the option to add that in the respective `subscribe()` blocks. Hope that helps!

Comment: It's great Nate, it is almost what I want, but this implementation doesn't return the response model when you called it in "loadDynamicProperties1" method, what if I want to set this subscribe result into a variable? if I do that, my local variable type would be this ```` (local var) result: Subscription ````

Comment: You may either do the assignment within the subscription, e.g. ...subscribe(res => this.myNonObservableLocalVar = res) OR what should be the best practise, assign the call to a local observable, e.g. myLocalVar$ = this.shopService.getAllDynamicProperties() and then either use the async pipe (myLocalVar$ | async) in your template, which handles the subscribe / unsubscribe or use it within another observable pipeline and subscribe there.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this quite wrong,

1. You are in angular, why are you using promises
2. If you really want to use promises, why not simply return using `.toPromise()`

Basically something like

```js
import {of, catchError} from 'rxjs';

export class ShopService {
  DYNAMIC_PROPERTY_GETALL_SELECT_ITEM_URL = environment.BASE_URL + 'DynamicProperty/GetAllSelecItem';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }

  getAllDynamicProperties(): Promise<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>> {
    
    return this.httpClient.get<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>>(this.DYNAMIC_PROPERTY_GETALL_SELECT_ITEM_URL)
      .pipe(
        catchError(() => {
          var result: ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO> = 
          ApiResultModelDTO.GetNullModel<SelectItemDTO>();
          return of(result)
        })
      )
      .toPromise()
    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you please comment the right form of this method in Angular ?!

Comment: Just remove the line `.toPromise()` and change the return type to `Observable<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>>`

Comment: I get this error when I remove ````.toPromise()```` "Type 'Observable<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<ApiResultModelDTO<SelectItemDTO>>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]"

Comment: you need to change the return type, see my earlier comment